# Accessing devices on the server's LAN over VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a VPN setup that allows me to tunnel home and access any home server running on the network.

However, I'm only able to use it from my Android device's mobile network or Macbook that's connected to a mobile hotspot. I'm able to connect to my OpenVPN server from any network, but connections just time out when the client device is connected to any home/work network (ISP, for the lack of a better term, in the log below).

Not sure if it's relevant, but here's what `arp` output looks like. I use OpenVPN Connect to connect to my OpenVPN server back home.

```
> # ISP 
> arp -a
iopsys.lan (192.168.1.1) at 34:e3:80:8c:b8:c0 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.117) at a4:98:13:44:93:c7 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.160) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
jbl-bar-9.lan (192.168.1.223) at 2c:fd:b3:d1:18:bc on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]

> # ISP + VPN tunnel home – can't access any home machine by its IP, although they are in the list below
> arp -a
? (192.168.1.1) at 34:e3:80:8c:b8:c0 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.117) at a4:98:13:44:93:c7 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.160) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.223) at 2c:fd:b3:d1:18:bc on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.224) at 24:6f:28:5b:bc:c0 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]

> # Mobile hotspot
> arp -a
? (192.168.146.123) at ce:30:4:ae:27:6c on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.146.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]

> # Mobile hotspot + VPN tunnel home – everything works, I can access all local IPs that aren't even listed in the table below
> arp -a
? (192.168.146.123) at ce:30:4:ae:27:6c on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.146.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

I think I'm missing part of how VPNs work, i.e. how are two networks (client's LAN and server's LAN) separated, if both use same IP ranges and what I want to do is access the server's LAN. I tried searching online, but I don't think I'm using the right keywords to find it.

I would highly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction as I would really like to understand how to make it work and why this behaviour occurs.

Comment: `if both use same IP ranges` you'll need to (temporarily) override the LAN prefix route on the client by some means then (e.g. ip rule), or maybe set up some whole-subnet one-to-one NAT that uses a different IP subnet to "represents" the server LAN's (and the fake one should be pushed as route to the clients).

Comment: @JW0914 thanks for the explanation, but I think I might have provided too much information. The issue seems to be an IP conflict and the Android/hotspot example was just to illustrate a contrasting behaviour, as I didn't exactly know what caused the behaviour.

Comment: @TomYan I'm wondering if it would be possible to override/sandbox my client machine in a different subnet, so it wouldn't clash with the host. I have quite a lot of configuration relying on IPs at home and it would be a chore to migrate to a different subnet. However, I don't usually need any specific configuration at a remote site except a working internet connection, so I could very well do something like isolate myself from the network.

Comment: @Lightheaded On Linux I think sometimes people use netns (network namespace) for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've learned from the answers that the issue is caused by IP conflicts / using the same subnets.

I've found a satisfactory solution for my current needs from a [question @Albin linked](https://serverfault.com/a/835400/444150) – temporarily routing an IP through the VPN's network interface:

```
sudo route add -host 192.168.1.25 -interface utun2
```

(I'm on macOS)

Thanks, everyone for thinking along. It's been a pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

To give you a bit more understanding on how the VPN works (since you asked and I don't know the extend of your background knowledge). In laymen's terms: you can think of the VPN client installed on your device as a virtual network card (same think you you use the OS's integrated VPN client). It gets it's IP from the VPN server and usually it will be a different subnet then the remote network your are trying to connect to through the VPN but that depends on the setup. Your VPN server acts as a router to access the remote network. Therefore the ARP table is not that relevant, you should rather look at the routing table and the interface configurations.

Without any further information about the configuration of the VPN its hard to help you.

- As a basic test you can use traceroute to check if the route to the target device is going through the VPN.
- Make sure you're the subnets don't overlap. If your local network has the same subnet as the "VPN network" or your remote network, there might be routing problems which can result in the effects you are experiencing. [Here's some further information on the topic form Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/548888/connecting-to-a-remote-server-through-a-vpn-when-the-local-network-subnet-addres).

Here's an example how your interface configurations and routing table will look (in principle):

```
192.168.100.1/24    your router's IP address
192.168.100.101/24  your client's IP address
192.168.200.201/24  your VPN-IP (the one your VPN client got assigned)  
172.29.29.2/32      the PPP connection's IP (used for the VPN)
```

This would be the table with VPN disabled:

```
Network Destination          Netmask        Gateway          Interface  Metric
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.100.1    192.168.100.101      30
[snip]
      192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
      192.168.100.1  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
    192.168.100.101  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
    192.168.100.255  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
[snip]
```

This would be the table with VPN enabled (note the extra route, that routes your non-local traffic through the VPN, it's the preferred route because of the lower metric and the three extra routes used for the remote network):

```
Network Destination          Netmask        Gateway          Interface  Metric
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  192.168.100.1    192.168.100.101      30
            0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        on-link        172.29.29.2       1
[snip]
      192.168.100.0    255.255.255.0        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
      192.168.100.1  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
    192.168.100.101  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
    192.168.100.255  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.100.101       1
[snip]
      192.168.200.0    255.255.255.0        on-link    192.168.200.201       1
    192.168.200.201  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.200.201       1
    192.168.200.255  255.255.255.255        on-link    192.168.200.201       1
[snip]
```

In this particular example all the traffic outside of the current LAN (in this example outside `192.168.100.0/24`) should routed through your VPN. If you do a traceroute let's say google.com you the traffic should be routed via `172.29.29.2` (through the VPN-PPP connection), without the VPN it should be routed via `192.168.100.1` (through your router). So

Please note, this is a simplified example, so you know the principles. It's based on a IPsec/l2tp VPN connection without a split tunnel (meaning all non-LAN traffic is going through the VPN). Your actual use case will be more complicated and different depending on how your VPN is configured.

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP really have misconception about VPN as the issue seems to be IP range conflict between the client's LAN and the server's LAN (i.e. not the VPN subnet). The arp part is probably just to showcase the problem.

Comment: @TomYan I'm not sure either (ergo "I think you have a misconception"), but using terms like "server LAN" instead of "remote LAN", is rather an indication that the OP is not a network admin ;) so I wanted to give him a bit of background knowledge. And yes I agree, looks a little like an IP range conflict.

Comment: I appreciate the background. I'm not a network admin indeed. I now know that it's an IP conflict (as I vaguely suspected but didn't know if it's the real cause and didn't know how to verify) and am trying to figure out a good solution.

Comment: P.S. I appreciate you sharing the correct term instead of just pointing out that it's wrong 

Comment: @Lightheaded You're welcome, glad I could help